# How to send a POST request via "Send HTTP Request" activity?

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I am trying to send a POST request for some dummy API {https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create}. In POSTMAN when I am hitting this api I am also using 2 headers as Name/Value pair and in the body I am passing some raw text, and I am able to successfully post it via POSTMAN.

For the same in TIBCO BW 6.5 studio, I am using "Send-HTTP-Request" activity,
in its "General" tab inside the "Parameters" section I have added they keys of my 2 headers, whose value I am passing in the Input tab 'parameters' section. In the input tab I have specified the 'host' as my {hostname} and port as 443 as it is an HTTPS call, Method I have kept as "POST" and RequestURI I have kept as '/api/v1/create'.

Inside the PostData I have kept my input body which I want to post.

But when I run this process in my studio the flow keeps on waiting in Send-HTTP-Request and do not proceed to next activity.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Rudra

Answer (score 0):

You need to set http header and not parameter tab. Refer to link for the answer.[set http headers in tibco bw 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242177/where-to-add-headers-in-send-http-request-in-tibco-bw-6-5/57655870#57655870)